# How to create a dictionary from input string in Python3

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a 4 lines in input that looks like:

```
first 10
second 20
third 30
fourth 40
```

And i want to create a dict with words as key and number as value:

```
{ 
    'first': 10,
    'second': 20,
    'third': 30'
    'fourth': 40
}
```

How to do this by using dict comprehension?
So this is working:

```
d = {}
for i in range(4):
    s = input().split()
    d[s[0]] = s[1]
```

And this is not:

```
x = {s: v for k in range(4) for s, v in input().split()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Jean has already provided an answer, thought I would add this as well which uses generator to get and split the input and then dict comprehension to form the dictionary.

```
{ k : v for k, v in (input().split() for _ in range(4)) }
```

Comment: And i can simply int(v) in it: `{ k : int(v) for k, v in (input().split() for _ in range(4)) }`
It's awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating on the value of the `split` result in the inner loop, where you just need to assign & unpack the split values. Unfortunately you cannot do that inside a list comprehension.

But you could pass a generator comprehension yielding couples instead of a dictionary comprehension

```
x = dict(input().split() for k in range(4))
```

that's simple but doesn't convert strings to integers, though. To convert the second item to integers while remaining in the list comprehension, you could use `enumerate` on the split result and test if this is the 2nd item using a ternary expression, which complexifies the line but yields the value as integer.

```
x = dict([int(x) if i==1 else x for i,x in enumerate(input().split())] for k in range(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're simply splitting on whitespace and that won't give you the desired pairs. It would give you a list of the words separated by whitespace (like `['first', '10', second', '20']`). Try something like:

`x = {item.split()[0]: item.split()[1] for item in input().split('\n')}`